# Why is this grep exclusion failed to work in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to do exclude certain characters when using grep in R. But I cannot get the result that I expect.

Here is the code:

```
x <- c("a", "ab", "b", "abc")
grep("[^b]", x, value=T)
> [1] "a"   "ab"  "abc"
```

I want to grab anything in vector `x` that does not contain `b`. It should not return `"ab"` or `"abc"`.

Ultimately I want to pick up any element that contains `"a"` but not `"b"`.
This is the result that I would expect:

```
grep("a[^b]", x, value=T)
> [1] "a"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep("^[^b]*a[^b]*$", x, value=TRUE)
# [1] "a"
```

It looks for the start of the string, then allows any number of characters that are not "b", then an "a", then any number of characters that are not "b" again and then the end of the string is reached.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `invert` property of `grep` which returns `values` which do not match. So here it returns those values which do not have "b" in them.

```
grep("b", x, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the result, what are you looking for, using this regular expression in grep:

```
grep("^[^b]*$", x, value=TRUE)  
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Not really. This regexp rejects `"aa"`.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But there wasn' task to accept "aa", using a regular expression. Anyway, adding "*" solve this issue.Yes? Finally, a regular expression should be  :  
              `grep("^[^b]*$", x, value=TRUE) `

Comment: The task was to reject anything that contains "b" => in particular, accept "aa".  I'm not an expert in regexp, but your new proposal seems to work.

Comment: But we've also got a reproducible example without any "aa" value.